# How to increment each printed row to the power 2 to the power of n and n-1 in C++?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

Trying to write a program in C++ that prints rows of "*" based on the result of 2^n then after a certain number is entered decrease 2^n-1.
For example any where between 0 and 6 (both of these being n) a row of stars is printed from *, **, **** and so forth. Then anything between 7 and 12 the number of stars decreases 2^n-1.

So far I have this but it only prints one singe line of * based on the result of the exponent.

```
int base = 2, exponent, result;
    char star = '*';

    cout << "Enter a number between 0 and 12:  ";
    cin >> exponent;

    result = pow(base, exponent);
    string pattern = string(result, star);
    cout << pattern << endl;

If user enters 4 
Output; ********
```

Goal for it to look like this

```
2^0 = *
2^1 = **
2^2 = ****
2^3 = ********
2^4 = ****************
2^5 = ********
2^6 = ****
2^7 = **
2^8 = *

Hope that makes sense.
```

Comment: u can use vector std::vector<char> pattern (result ,star ); and print the vector

Comment: Unrelated: `pow(base, exponent)` operates on floating point numbers. When you convert floats back to integers you sometimes find out that float contained something like 9.99999999 rather than the expected 10 and gets truncated to 9. Really sucks. General recommendation is to stay in integers and use multiplication. In this case you're after powers of 2, and 2 to the `n` is the same as `1 << n`.

Comment: You need a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the problem is that you need a loop, i tried to not edit your variables this is the best i could do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int base = 2, exponent, result;
    char star = '*';
    int aux=1;
    cout << "Enter a number between 0 and 12:  ";
    cin >> exponent;
    for(int i=0;i<=exponent;i++)
    {
        cout <<" 2 ^ "<<i<<" = ";
        result = pow(base, i);
        for(int j=1;j<=result;j++)
        {
            cout<<star;
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    aux=exponent;
    for(int i=exponent-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        cout <<" 2 ^ "<<aux<<" = ";
        aux++;
        result = pow(base, i);
        for(int j=1;j<=result;j++)
        {
            cout<<star;
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

the first for loop is when the numbers are under the exponent and the other are for when the numbers are above the exponent. Hope that helps you, i will provide further help if needed!

This is the photo of the run window
[click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymBCZ.png)

Comment: This was really helpful thank you so much. Just for clarification, I am not sure what the aux = 1 means in the 2nd iteration could you please clarify?

Comment: Well, the answer is that i am sometimes stupid and i forgot to delete it haha, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are taking the input and storing it in your exponent variable, and then only printing once.

What you want to do is create a loop that varies your exponent up to maximum value based on the input you got.

i.e. for the increasing part

```
int max_num;
cin >> max_num 
for (int i; i < max_num; i++){
   // code to print 2^n stars, with n=i 
}
```

You can write a similar loop for the decreasing part by counting down.

```
int max_num;
cin >> max_num 
for (int i; i >= 0; i--){
   // code to print 2^n stars, with n=i 
}
```

Comment: This was very helpful especially the counting down part, ill try these out in the code

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i needed to edit your code.
you have to use iteration for you to achieve that output.

```
    int rvalue = 1;
    int i;
    string outputDisplay = "";

    int base_ = 2;
    int exponent = 0;
    cout << "Enter a number between 0 and 12:  ";
    cin >> exponent;



    for (i = 1; i <= exponent; i++)
        rvalue = rvalue * base_;

    while (rvalue != 0)
    {
        outputDisplay += "*";
        rvalue--;
    }
    cout << outputDisplay << endl;
```

On this part im getting the X^n output without using any library (Math.Pow for example).

```
  for (i = 1; i <= exponent; i++)
            rvalue = rvalue * base_;
```

For the output you just need to add "*" on a string depending on the
rvalue or the X^n value.

```
 while (rvalue != 0)
        {
            outputDisplay += "*";
            rvalue--;
        }
```

On this case i inputted 2 and 4 initially on the variable,
output will be like;
[image]

Another run;
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much I was really stuck on the iteration part.

Comment: dont forget to upvote if this had helped you :)

Comment: I would love to but I'm so new at this that I have less than 15 reputations lol. I started taking an intro programming class a month ago.

Comment: Note:: for `base_` of 2, `for (i = 1; i <= exponent; i++) rvalue = rvalue * base_;` reduces to `rvalue <<= exponent;`. Because of binary representations, every bit you shift a number to the left doubles the number.